Laravel dynamic charts using chartjs
I have a website with transactions and I want to build transactions that are dynamically created with specific filters for each.
I am not sure what the right approach would be to do this. I have one idea how to do this, but I feel like it's very poor and might generate a giant json file and slow the page load if not worse
My idea is to do it like this:

Get all the chart data from a "charts" table in DB.
Get the associated filters with that "chart" from another table in DB.
Filter the data from the data table used for the dataset.
The controller then passes the dataset as a json inside a  tag for the view
In the view, using that json I build each chart

I feel like the json file the controller sends to the view may grow large if I have more charts on the page. I would also prefer I have the option to use lazy-loading so each chart only loads and possibly makes requests for it's data using ajax only when it's in view, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that, so I'd love some hints towards a good approach.
